array of records without jq's "slurp"

My customer is producing enormous json-like files, using automation. For this reason they can be enormous; tens of gigabytes or more; I cannot control these files in size or in content.

The files aren't valid json; they tend to be sequential json records without separators between them.  They look sort of like this:
{ "a":1, "b": 2, ... }
{ "a":2, "b": 4, ... }
{ "a":3, "b": 6, ... }


Our software runs at customer site, autonomously, without my team being present after the initial setup.

Customers have many files, and I have many customers. Custom coding is a last resort.

I have jq in my environment. I would prefer to use what I already have.


Given the above set-up, I fear jq -s will load entire multi-gigabyte files into memory.
I need to convert the above semi-json into something valid like:
[
{ 'a':1, 'b': 2, ... },
{ 'a':2, 'b': 4, ... },
{ 'a':3, 'b': 6, ... }
]

and I would like to stream the json while I make this conversion to reduce resource consumption.
Using jq --slurp ".", the files are converted to the desired array-of-records.  However slurp pulls the entire file into memory and that's not ok.
Using jq what's an alternative "streaming" method?

"I need to fix the format before I try to process the file."  I disagree.  Most json parsers are going to have the same problem; it's going to want to load the entire array into memory.   Json is not a streaming format.  It's better to have the smaller documents.  Read the individual json documents from the file one by one.  What language are you using?

I don't know how you can disagree with the facts of my situation.  My json parser streams. And I do not control the files and have no say in their formats or size.

All you have to do is read the json documents one after another from the same open file.  Slurping them all up into one big json file is moving in the wrong direction.  A smart json parser might be able to overcome this, but most aren't truly streaming (eg Go encoding/json).  What parser is it?

I agree, slurping them is the wrong way to go.  Looks like we're using Jackson Streaming API, through this is not relevant to the question.

This question is focused on turning the concatentated json documents into one big json document, right?  I'm saying, don't.  Read them one by one off the open file stream and collate the data yourself; in raw Java it will be a lot  more efficient than in json, especially if there's a lot of numbers in the data, which if it's sensors, there probably are.  you can do that with with your Jackson Streaming API I think.  Not one big document; many small documents.

That whole point notwithstanding, have you tried jq -s instead of jq -s "."?  Your version explicitly says, "and your result shall be the entirety of the document you read in".  idk if it would effect memory though.

Any json library worth its salt will see that document and process the first record at a minimum with no issues and can continue reading the following records, assuming they are each valid json. Preprocessing just to put it into a different format is counterproductive at those sizes. You don't need to read it all in at once, depending on your flavor of language, write a generator that will read each record and go from there. You're just looking for a world of hurt right now and future you/coworkers will hate you for it.

"they tend to be sequential json records without separators between them": It appears that there are separators — line feed characters (\n) — which would make the format streaming JSON (e.g. JSON Lines). Is that the case?

[Note: the following is a response to the original question, in which the input was described as a sequence of newline-delimited JSON-like records, with the suggestion that each record might be a valid hjson value that was not valid JSON.]

I need to fix the format before I try to process the file.

First, please notice that the proposed "fix" is at best incomplete, as in JSON, the keys must be JSON strings (i.e., with double-quotes).
Second, if your preferred tool requires you to have a single ginormous JSON file, then as others have suggested, the problem is with your preference in that regard.  Since you have indicated a willingness to use jq, please note that the C, Go and Rust implementations thereof all handle JSON streams very nicely, without any need to engage is slurpiness.
Thirdly, there are any number of approaches for converting a quasi-JSON stream such as you have described to a stream of valid JSON entities.
I'd focus my attention there.

Unfortunately the hjson CLI program does not handle streams, and it would probably be unwise to invoke the program zillions of times, so here's a simple Python program that could be used on new-line-delimited log files:
import hjson

def process_json_line_by_line(stream):
    for line in stream:
        line = line.strip()  # Remove leading/trailing whitespace
        if not line:
            continue  # Skip empty lines
        try:
            # Parse the line as Hjson
            obj = hjson.loads(line)
            print(hjson.dumpsJSON(obj))
        except hjson.HjsonDecodeError as e:
            print("Failed to parse line:", line)
            print("Error:", e)

with open('test.qjson', 'r') as file:
    process_json_line_by_line(file)



As @pmf pointed out, once the stream of (hjson?) measurements has been converted to a JSON stream, you can use jq to convert that to a JSON array efficiently (i.e. without slurping) by:
jq -r '"[", ., (inputs | ",", .), "]"'


My preferred tool does not "require" me to have ginormous files. My customer requires it.  I am simply dealing with the reality.  I have no preference except that jq is already installed in the environment I must use.

It seems odd that your customer would require you to produce a file that is impractical to read, but if that's the requirement, you could combine a stream-oriented rectification step (perhaps using hjson) with the jq program shown by @pmf.  Or perhaps even better, you could do everything in one step by adding the punctuation in the Python program.

No, the customer is generating them with sensors.

@TonyEnnis - In the initial description of the problem, you described very large log files, and said "I need a valid json file" and gave as an example the slurped version of the log files.  Are you saying now that the customer is requiring you to produce the unmanageably large JSON, or that they are producing it independently of your work?  The discussion is becoming quite confusing, though the solution is clearer than ever: a JSON stream (JSON for standards conformance, and stream for manageability).

you are correct, the question isn't clear. I rephrased it, though there could still be too many words.


The files aren't valid json; they tend to be sequential json records without separators between them.

So long as the input consists of “sequential JSON records” (with or without whitespace between them), jq can handle it. To convert such input to ndjson (i.e. a stream of newline-delimited JSON records), you could simply use jq ., but in practice, you will probably want to have the ability to recover from errors, so your jq invocation will probably look something like
jq -Rn 'recurse(try (inputs|fromjson) catch .) | select(.)'

For files which consist of hjson objects that are not JSON objects, then if the individual objects are newline-separated, then you could use the Python hjson package as explained elsewhere on this page. Otherwise, you will probably have a difficult choice: try some hackery (e.g. repairing the damage using sed); write your own parser; remonstrate with the customer; or abandon said customer.

As long as each document is guaranteed to be on its own line (i.e. a JSONL file), this a shell-only solution to achieve what you want:
printf '['
if read -r line; then
   printf '\n%s' "$line"
   while read -r line; do
      printf ',\n%s' "$line"
   done
fi
printf '\n]\n'

It reads from STDIN, so you could place the code in a file and use
./fix <a.jsonl

Or you can inline it into an existing shell script using
{
   # Place the code provided above here.
} <a.jsonl

For example,
$ cat a.jsonl
{ "a":1, "b": 2 }
{ "a":2, "b": 4 }
{ "a":3, "b": 6 }

$ {
   printf '['
   if read -r line; then
      printf '\n%s' "$line"
      while read -r line; do
         printf ',\n%s' "$line"
      done
   fi
   printf '\n]\n'
} <a.jsonl
[
{ "a":1, "b": 2 },
{ "a":2, "b": 4 },
{ "a":3, "b": 6 }
]


Alternative streaming methods using jq:
# METHOD #1: 
# Add comma after every line. 
# Requires an additional step to remove last comma and add brackets
jq --stream -Rr '"\(.),"' file1.txt file2.txt

# Skip comma on empty lines
# if length > 0 then "\(.)," else "" end


# METHOD #2:
# Read each line and return an array of objects (or "" if there was an error)
# I think this is your solution.
jq --stream -R '[., inputs]|map(fromjson? // "")' file*.txt


# METHOD #3: 
# A streamable json parser
jq --stream -c -R 'fromjson' file*.txt


Example using #2
$ cat file1.txt 
{ "a":1, "b": 2 }
{ "a":2, "b": 4 }

$ cat file2.txt 
{"html": "This is a sentence."}
{"html": "This is another sentence."}

$ cat file3.txt 
1
2

$ cat file4.txt
{"error": "i am missing a bracket"

$ jq --stream -R '[., inputs]|map(fromjson? // "")' file*.txt
[
  {"a":1,"b":2},
  {"a":2,"b":4},
  {"html":"This is a sentence."},
  {"html":"This is another sentence."},
  1,
  2,
  ""
]

